# polygon to raster with raster as cell size

Tags: polygon, raster

I have a shapefile and a raster file which I want to merge. Normally I would *Extract by mask* the rasterfile to obtain delineation of the shapefile. But now the shapefile has sub-delineation inside which I want to keep. One way to do this is *Polygon to raster* where I choose the raster-file inside cell size. However when I do this the right uppper coordiante is off the chart with values of 10^4 for a WGS 1984 decimal degree georeference. The projection of the two files do not seem to make any difference.

ArcGis 10.1

Comment: could you provide some data? What you mean by sub-delineation inside the shapefile?

Comment: The solution was to do the analysis with a raster image in 1984 decimal degree (I had tried it with UTM projection), as it is a global  analysis

Comment: So have you a solution? Would you like to share?

Comment: If I kept the analysis with maps of 1984 projection instead of UTM then I managed